# Как с помощью регулярного выражения разбить строку

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Имеется строка:

Runaway Train SOUL ASYLUM или Fading Like A Flower ROXETTE

Как в Java c помощью регулярного выражения преобразовать (по первому слову в котором все буквы заглавные) в:

SOUL ASYLUM - Runaway Train

ROXETTE - Fading Like A Flower

Comment: т.е.есть строка в которой часть слов строчные а часть написано заглавными и их нужно местами поменять?

Comment: да, поменять местами исполнителя и название трека, может быть и такая строка - Обещай Мне МАРШАЛ Александр, надо сделать МАРШАЛ Александр - Обещай Мне.

Comment: А почему вам нужно сделать это именно регуляркой? Чтобы жизнь мёдом не казалась?

Comment: посоветуйте другое решение )

Comment: Начните сканировать посимвольно с **конца** строки. До тех пор, пока не встретите первую строчную букву сохраняйте символы в подстроку `А`, а после того, как появилась строчная и до конца строки (вернее, до её начала), сохраните в подстроку `B`. Т.о. в `A` у вас будет исполнитель, а в `B` - название.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот мое решение:

```
private static String revert(String content) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\p{IsUppercase}]{2,}", Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        int index = matcher.start();
        return content.substring(index) + " - " + content.substring(0, index);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось! :) Только не "[\\p{IsUppercase}]{2,}" а "[\\p{Upper}]{2,}"

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html у меня так работало